# Can this integral be solved analytically?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the following integral, where $x,y,z>0$ and $x>y$. The integrand is divergent at $x=y$, but from numerical integration it seems that the integral is finite for all $x,y,z$.

$f(x,y,z)=\int_0^\pi d\phi\left[\ln \left(\sqrt{z^2+x^2-2 x y \cos (\phi)+y^2}-z \right)-3 \ln \left(\sqrt{z^2 + x^2-2 x  y \cos (\phi)+y^2}+z \right)\right]$

Does an analytical solution to this problem exist?

**Edit:**

By try and error, I have found that

$F(x,y,z)=\frac{\pi}{z}  \left[8 \sqrt{x^2+z^2}+z \log \left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-z\right)-3 z \log \left(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}+z\right)-8 x\right]-16 \sqrt{(x+y)^2+z^2} \, E\left(\frac{4 x y}{(x+y)^2+z^2}\right)+16 (x+y) E\left(\frac{4 x y}{(x+y)^2}\right)$

with the complete elliptic integral $E$ as used by mathematica gives an excellent approximation of $f$ for all $y$ if $x\gg z$ (e.g., for $x=100z$).

For those eager to try, here the mathematica code of the functions to copy-paste:

```
f[x_, y_, z_, \[Phi]_] := 
 Log[-z + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 x y Cos[\[Phi]]]] - 
  3 Log[z + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2 x y Cos[\[Phi]]]]
F[x_, y_, z_] := 
 1/z (16 (x + y) EllipticE[(4 x y)/(x + y)^2] - 
    16 Sqrt[(x + y)^2 + z^2]
      EllipticE[(
      4 x y)/((x + y)^2 + z^2)] + \[Pi] (-8 x + 8 Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] + 
       z Log[-z + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]] - 3 z Log[z + Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]]))
Block[{x = 1., z = 0.01}, 
 Plot[{NIntegrate[f[x, y, z, \[Phi]], {\[Phi], 0, Pi}], 
   F[x, y, z]}, {y, 0, x}]]
```

Could that be a hint to the correct result for all $x,y,z$?

Comment: Where did this problem come up? The inside of the square root reminds me of the law of cosines, but the logarithms confuse me a but. What makes you think this would have a closed form?

Comment: It is part of the integral of $\frac{1}{|r-r^\prime|}$ in cylindrical coordinates, where the integration with respect to $z,z^\prime,$ and $\phi^\prime$ has been carried out. The term $\frac{1}{|r-r^\prime|}$ is the interaction kernel for magnetic charges. In my situation, the charges depend only on the radial coordinate and therefore I would like to perform as many of the remaining integrals as possible in advance. I don't know if it has a closed form.

Comment: Have you ran the integral through wolfram alpha or mathematica yet? I'm currently out of town without a steady Internet connection (other than the phone I'm using) but I'll check it out when I get back... My guess is that by playing around with the constants a bit and absorbing them into one or two constants this can be simplified enough that Mathematica will work.

Comment: Mathematica can't solve it in the present form. I have not yet found a form that it can solve. But also, I am new to mathematica, so probably there are tricks that I don't know of. I'm curious to see your suggestions.

Comment: alrighty, I'll take a look at it when I get back and let you know if I find anything